# how to flat subarray into array in dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

i have this input

```
[{
    "omsNo": "S001",
    "recipient": [{
            "name": "name1",
            "address": "address1"
        },
        {
            "name": "name2",
            "address": "address2"
        }
    ]
}]
```

may i know how to get this result using dataweave

```
[{"omsNo":"S001","name":"name1","address":"address1"},{"omsNo":"S001","name":"name2","address":"address2"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Input**

```
[{
    "omsNo": "S001",
    "recipient": [{
            "name": "name1",
            "address": "address1"
        },
        {
            "name": "name2",
            "address": "address2"
        }
    ]
}]
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten(payload map ((item, index) -> 
   (item.recipient map ((itemRecipient, indexRecipient)  -> (
        ({omsNo: item.omsNo} ++ itemRecipient) 
   ))
)))
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "omsNo": "S001",
    "name": "name1",
    "address": "address1"
  },
  {
    "omsNo": "S001",
    "name": "name2",
    "address": "address2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.recipient[0] map (v0,k0) ->
{
    omsNo:payload.omsNo[0],
    name:v0.name,
    address:v0.address
}
```

Comment: It's working but I think the proper selector should be `payload[0].recipient` and `payload[0].omsNo`

Comment: Ok @Jorge Garcia.  Do you mind explaining why the selector you mentioned is more appropriate. 

Comment: Sure, sorry. If we look at the original input, the payload is an array with one object inside, so first, you select the first object of the array and then ask for the `recipient` field of that object. That selection is more direct. Your code is also working because DataWeave selectors automatically generate an array when any of the items in the selector is an array, and then collect the leaves, but you may get inconsistent behaviors if there are more objects in the arrays or you have more levels of arrays.

Comment: Thanks @JorgeGarcia, appreciate the effort to explain !